# Change orientation of a shape

Tags: delphi, vcl

I would like to know if there is a way to change the orientation of a TShape thus instead of a square , i would like to rotate it to look like a diamond..

If not a way with TShape, how could this be done?

Comment: vcl   not a big fan of firemonkey yet,  still too many issues

Comment: Maybe you should also include the Delphi version you use. The answer by Remy is the most practical and works since Delphi 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A TShape itself cannot be rotated.  But you can use a TPaintBox to draw your own graphics anyway you wish, it is just a matter of mathematically plotting the points to draw between.  For example:

```
procedure TForm1.PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject);
var
  Points: array[0..3] of TPoint;
  W, H: Integer;
begin
  W := PaintBox1.Width;
  H := PaintBox1.Height;

  Points[0].X := W div 2;
  Points[0].Y := 0;

  Points[1].X := W;
  Points[1].Y := H div 2;

  Points[2].X := Points[0].X;
  Points[2].Y := H;

  Points[3].X := 0;
  Points[3].Y := Points[1].Y;

  PaintBox1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBtnFace;
  PaintBox1.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0, 0, W, H));

  PaintBox1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlue;
  PaintBox1.Canvas.Pen.Color := clBlack;
  PaintBox1.Canvas.Pen.Width := 1;
  PaintBox1.Canvas.Polygon(Points);
end;
```

Answer (score 8):

A Delphi TShape is nothing more than drawing a bunch of vector graphics.

You can "rotate" the X/Y coordinates themselves with a 2-D transformation matrix.  Computer Graphics 101:

- http://www.cs.uic.edu/~jbell/CourseNotes/ComputerGraphics/2DTransforms.html
- http://www.willamette.edu/~gorr/classes/GeneralGraphics/Transforms/transforms2d.htm

Comment: +1; good references on 2D transformations. The second one is very visual.